# run python in visual studio express 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-express, python-install

I'am using visual studio express 2017 and I'd like to use it to developp in python. The thing is that I find many installation tutorial to use it with Community (or upper) but not Express.

I can't change for Community so, do you know if there is a solution ? the important point is that I have no workload to install via the installer. Actually, the installer is pretty empty as the only thing I have in it is the installed langages and the installation directory.

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can help ? I am currently with VSCode for my python code, but I found it less usefull thant Visual Studio